# Why can't I call an HTTP Handler through Ajax?

Tags: ajax, httphandler

I have a very simple page. An image that gets populated on the server side by an httphandler.

I don't want the ENTIRE page updated, so I wrapped that image with a button in an update panel. Then it stopped working. Why?

Here is the image that points to the httphandler:

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnImage" runat="server"  
ImageUrl='<%#"~\Handlers\Handler.ashx?id=23%>' CommandArgument='23'/>
```

Comment: What are you doing to that poor `ImageUrl` attribute? Your backslashes should be escaped, but URLs need *forward* slashes anyway, and what's with the binding expression? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The image points to a handler which gets the bytes from a db based on the id and serves it out. I know of no other way to display an image from a db.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ImageUrl="~/Handlers/Handler.ashx?id=23"` then? Or am I completely lost?

Comment: That hasn't been an issue at all. I've displayed many images and in fact, this page does tp, until I introduce Ajax and the UpdatePanel.